# Prevent moving forward of a function until HTTP Request returns a value

Tags: java, android, http

I have a HTTP Request sent to a server with some action and parameters. It returns a response. I want this function to wait until it gets the response and maps the data as per my choice( eg- set value to object class for Event). It will then return this data to the function from where it was called.

For example:
I am calling getEventWithID from here:

```
public uk.co.createanet.bloc.Networking.DynamoDB.Mapping.Event fetchAdvertEvent(Long eventID) {
        return EventHelper.getEventWithID(eventID);
    }
```

getEventWithID - This calls the HTTP request and get the response. I want this function not to return until it receives the response from server.

```
public static Event getEventWithID(Long eventID, IHelperRequestCompletion<Event> completion) {

        Event event = new Event();

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("eventID", eventID);

        HttpHelper.getInstance().makeApiHttpRequestNewServer("get-event", params, new IHelperRequestCompletion<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    event.setID(response.getLong("uniqueID"));
                    event.setPlaceID(response.getLong("placeID"));
                    event.setType(response.getString("type"));
                    event.setTimestamp(response.getDouble("date"));
                    if(response.toString().contains("people")){
                        JSONArray attendingPPL = response.getJSONArray("people");
                        Set<Long> attendingPPLList = new HashSet<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < attendingPPL.length(); i++) {
                            attendingPPLList.add(Long.parseLong(attendingPPL.getString(i)));
                        }
                        event.setAttendingPeopleIDs(attendingPPLList);
                    }

                    if(event.getID()!=null) {
                        AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(BlocApplication.getAppContext()).eventDao().insertAll(event);
                        if(completion !=null){
                            completion.onResponse(event);
                        }
                    }

                }catch (Exception err){
                    Log.v("Error in getEventByID", err.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.v("Error in getEventByID", error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        });

return event;
    }
```

Comment: your function look fine, its return when response came

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an async call and returning a value then this function is not going to work, for achieving that kind of functionality you have to create an interface and return value through listeners.